# How to set an icon for external launcher on Windows with install4j?

Tags: windows, install4j

How can I set with install4j a custom icon for an program that uses an external launcher?

Answer (score 0):

The icon for an executable is contained in the executable itself. install4j cannot inject icons into external executables, so the icon that is displayed in the explorer cannot be changed by install4j.

For actions that create links, you can specify an icon, for example the "Add a desktop link" action has an "Add a desktop link" action.